# Finite family of red and blue lines

Tags: discrete-geometry

Let a finite family of red and blue lines in the planes be given. Assume no two given lines are parallel and through any intersection point of two lines of the same color, there passes a line of the other color. Prove that all the given lines, in fact, have a common point.